# How to collapse multiple call of the same function in clickhouse?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table with data:

| user | items |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 2 |

And I need to find how many users have more than 1 item, more than 2 and until inf.
I can use `SELECT uniqExactIf(user, items >= 1), uniqExactIf(user, items >= 2)...`, but how to make it shorter without calling uniqExactIf for infinite times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
create table data (user int, items int) Engine = Memory;
insert into data values (1,     9)(2,   8)(3,   7)(4,   2);
insert into data values (11,    9)(12,  8)(13,  7)(14,  2);
insert into data values (111,   9)(112,     8);

--slow

SELECT
    items,
    uniqExactMerge(s) OVER (ORDER BY items DESC Rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS _uniq
FROM
(
    SELECT
        items,
        uniqExactState(user) AS s
    FROM data
    GROUP BY items
)
┌─items─┬─_uniq─┐
│     9 │     3 │
│     8 │     6 │
│     7 │     8 │
│     2 │    10 │
└───────┴───────┘

--faster but could be incorrect on blocks bounds

SELECT
    items,
    runningAccumulate(s) AS _uniq
FROM
(
    SELECT
        items,
        uniqExactState(user) AS s
    FROM data
    GROUP BY items
    ORDER BY items DESC
)
┌─items─┬─_uniq─┐
│     9 │     3 │
│     8 │     6 │
│     7 │     8 │
│     2 │    10 │
└───────┴───────┘

-- as a single column
SELECT CAST(((groupArray((items, _uniq)) AS a).1, a.2), 'Map(Int64, Int64)') AS r
FROM
(
    SELECT
        items,
        runningAccumulate(s) AS _uniq
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            items,
            uniqExactState(user) AS s
        FROM data
        GROUP BY items
        ORDER BY items DESC
    )
)
┌─r──────────────────┐
│ {9:3,8:6,7:8,2:10} │
└────────────────────┘
```

Comment: runningAccumulate with descending ordering, great advice, thank you so much!